# CAS for counting points of varieties over finite fields

Tags: reference-request, finite-fields, math-software, arithmetic-geometry, computer-algebra-systems

I am looking for a computer algebra system that is able to do some of the following (equivalent in theory) things for a smooth projective variety defined over a finite field:

- Count the number of points defined over a certain field extension.
- Compute the eigenvalues of Frobenius on etale Cohomology.
- Compute the Zeta function.

Comment: I'm no expert, but [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) would be my guess

Comment: In the past my colleagues have used MAGMA to find answers to (at least) the first question.